# React router not render component after using history.push

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, mobx, mobx-react

I'm develop react application. I'm using this depencies:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
```

(for ui framework I'm using SemanticUI)

I'm initialize application this way

```
export const startup = async () => {
    const history: History = createBrowserHistory();
    const rootStore: RootStore = await RootStore.build(history);
    const app = <App history={history} rootStore={rootStore}/>;
    return { rootStore, app }
}
```

and I have three components:

1. Index component

```
startup().then(x => {
    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    console.log(x);
    const history = x.rootStore.history;

    reactRender(
        <>

            <BrowserRouter>
                <Provider history={x.rootStore.history} rootStore={x.rootStore}>
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
                        <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutComponent}/>
                    </Router>
                </Provider>
            </BrowserRouter>

        </>,
        root
    );
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    alert('can not initialize application')
})
```

2. Home page component

```
export interface HomePageProps {
    rootStore?: RootStore;
}

class HomePage extends React.Component<HomePageProps> {

    public constructor(props: HomePageProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <Button onClick={this.handler}>
                    go about
                </Button>
            </>
        )
    }

    public handler = () => {
        this.props.rootStore?.history!.push('/about');
        console.log(this.props.rootStore?.history);
    }

}

export default inject('rootStore')(observer(HomePage))
```

3. And about component

```
export interface AboutComponentProps {
    rootStore?: RootStore;
}

class AboutComponent extends React.Component<AboutComponentProps> {
    public constructor(props:AboutComponentProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h2>About</h2>
                <Button onClick={this.handler}>
                    go to home
                </Button>
            </>
        );
    }

    public handler = () => {
        this.props.rootStore?.history!.push('/');
    }
}
export default inject('rootStore')(observer(AboutComponent))
```

And after I click "go to home" or "go to about" the url change in browser address bar but new component not changed (not rendered)

This is bugs in new version? Or this is can be somehow solve?

P/S
You can check this bug in codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-gates-9gkuf

Comment: Why do you have 2 routers? `Router` and `BrowserRouter`? Also might be something related that you creating your own history instance (again why do you need it, why not use default one?) Also, would be great if you could post reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I'm creating my own history instance because i wanna inject in other components and follow the links from the code.

Comment: You don't need to create your own instance to do so. Just use https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter or even better use hooks api https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks but it would require you to use modern functional components. Anyway, why two routers?

Comment: I'm using two routers because I'm in despair :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use react hooks because I use strucutre based on class

Comment: Check here https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-gates-9gkuf

Comment: It definitely not working(

Comment: I've removed all unused parts of the code and changed import to `react-router-dom`, everything is working fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69350565-1qd0d?file=/src/index.tsx Maybe you need to change it in your original code too?

Comment: Thank you) So. the way with create instance of history and using router component this is not more need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. the way with create instance of history and using router component this is not more need.
Here an example.

Index component

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <HomeComponent />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

and here a test component

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';

interface HomeProps extends RouteComponentProps {}

class HomeComponent extends React.Component<HomeProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/component')}>
          go to component
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(HomeComponent);
```